# Is there a way to get list of devices that scanned for WiFi on the Access Point?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, wifi, access-point

I hope I've posted the question on the right place. Not so sure if it should be here or in ServerFault.Nonetheless thank you for those who will answer.

So we have this project where we want to get the SSIDs and/or MAC addresses of scanned WiFi Networks available via the iPhone (can't change devices now, so no do it on Android answers please). Since via iOS5 it has become completely impossible for non-jailbroken iPhones to do so (not sure) because of new security restrictions, I want to know if the opposite is possible. That is, is there any Access Point available that can record the information of the devices that did a scan, and put it in the syslog?

Or can you please suggest another way? The basic idea is that the iPhone must get a data from another device (in this case WiFi, and we're also thinking about bluetooth) and send it to a server.

**EDIT:**
I've read that it's possible to get the current SSID using CaptiveNetwork.h, can someone provide me information about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iphone-wireless project](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/) looks like it might fit the bill. Specifically [Apple80211GetInfoCopy](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211GetInfoCopy)

Comment: It does. But Apple added some restriction in accessing that method. It's being discussed [here](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/issues/detail?id=45&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Subproject), and they said it now requires super user access, so the app must be a native app to use it.
+1 though for the effort. Thanks.

Comment: Since nobody gave another answer, I'll accept this answer for now.